# Inverted Index Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of the form:

```
{: [ , {}]}
```

For example:

```
d = {term: [number, {number1: number2}]}
```

I tried to create the dictionary inside but I'm new and I couldn't understand how it's possible. The problem is that I want the form of d and I want to update number or the dictionary that contains number1 as key and number2 as value when finding term.

So the question is:
Is it possible to create a dictionary like d ? And if so, how can I access  term, number and the inside dictionay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {"term": [5, {6: 7}]}
```

The key's value is a list:

```
d["term"]   
[5, {6: 7}]
```

The list 's 1st element:

```
d["term"][0]
5
```

The list 's second element is a dictionary:

```
d["term"][1]
{6: 7}
```

The value of the dictionary's key '6' is 7:

```
d["term"][1][6]
7
```

**Edit:**
Some examples for modification:

```
d = {"term": [5, {6: 7}]}

d["term"].append(10)
print(d)
Out: {'term': [5, {6: 7}, 10]}

l=d["term"]
l[0]=55
print(d)
Out: {'term': [55, {6: 7}, 10]}

insidedict=l[1]
print(insidedict)
{6: 7}

insidedict[66]=77
print(d)
{'term': [55, {6: 7, 66: 77}, 10]}
```

Comment: If I have multiple keys ,say term , term1 , termk how can I add values in the inside dictionary of term or update term's numbers or update term's inside dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just define it as you have:

```
d = {'term': [5, {6: 7}]}
```

Since your dictionary has just one key, you an access the key via:

```
key = next(iter(d))
```

You can then access the value `5` via a couple of ways:

```
number = d[key][0]
number = next(iter(d.values()))[0]
```

Similarly, you can access the inner dictionary via either:

```
inner_dict = d[key][1]
inner_dict = next(iter(d.values()))[1]
```

And repeat the process for `inner_dict` if you want to access *its* key / value.

Comment: First, I would like to create an empty dictionary of the form {: [ , {}]} . Can you show me an example ?

Comment: @Devilhorn, Just instantiate it with `d = {'': [0, {0: 0}]}`, though I'm not sure why this is helpful. Python isn't strongly typed, you don't need to define in advance the type of every key and value.

Comment: Thank's @jpp , I instantiated it outside the loop I'm using it with the first values I need and it worked perfectly. As for the empty dictionary I was curious to find a way for educational purposes..

Comment: I have another problem, how can I get only the keys of the inside dictionary. For instance: say inside dictionary is :{name1:5,name2:2,name3:7} I need to check if name4 is in the inside dictionary as key , if not add it with empty value .
So the dictionary in that case would be: inside dict is: {name1:5,name2:2,name3:7,name4:''} else  if name4 is in dictionary it would remain the same.

Comment: I found that if I reach inside dict with: d[term][1].keys() I get all the keys but I don't know how to continue